# Environment Variables tab is missing from intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

The option to add environment variables is missing from my intellij ide I am editing a gradle tasks currently and want to add environment variables to it. How do I enable it?

Comment: What IDE version do you use? UI for adding environment variables for Gradle task    appear since 2017.2 version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115426. Also see another way of doing it from gradle script: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115426#focus=streamItem-27-610182-0-0

Comment: @Andrey i am using 2017.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Andrey the UI element for adding environment variables has been added in intellij version 2017.2 and onwards